# Remove image while changing page size

Tags: html, css, image, image-size

I've got a question about html and css (PURE html and css - no JavaScript or JQuery)

I've got 2 columns on my page (first - width:35% (page), second - width: 65% (page)). There is an image in the first column - 300px x 300px. And, I'm changing size of my page:

- When the first column is wider than 300px - the image should be 300px x 300px
- When the first column is wider than 100px and narrower than 300px - the image should be 100px x 100px
  -When the first column is narrower then 100px - the image should disappear.

It is very easy using JavaScript, but I have to do it only in HTML + CSS.

Does someone know how to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: couldn't you just give the image a % width and height also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using CSS3 Media Queries, however this of course is NOT supported by all browsers (that's just a given):

**EXAMPLE:**
The following CSS will apply if the viewing area is smaller than 600px.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .class {
    background: #ccc;
  }
}
```

**Reference:**
http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css3-media-queries

Comment: I agree with the suggestion to use media queries. Additionally, if you use a stylesheet that is set for a small display (i.e. max-width: 320px) at the baseline, you can set something like img{display:none;}, then overwrite the value later in the cascade if min-width: 640px (or any width) by setting img{display:block}. Be warned that older versions of IE will read ALL css and ignore media queries though, so controlling the cascade is extremely important